# Service layer with Data Transfer Objects (DTO)

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a multi module maven based application based on the following modules:

1. Model, contains all the Domain Entities
2. Persistence, contains all the Repository (or DAO) used to access the models
3. Service, contains all the business logic
4. Web, contains all the controllers logic to expose rest API

The problem I'm trying to figure out is about the DTO mapping, right now the dependency are organized in a linear way:

```
  Model <- Persistence <- Service <- Web
```

Where all the DTO logic should belong? Let's say we have a method inside the **service layer** called

```
createRoom(CreateRoomDTO createRoomDTO)
```

in this case the **CreateRoomDTO** class is highly coupled with the service and web modules, but not all the DTO classes are used by the service layer (for example a PaginationFilter)

Comment: in common, you can use DTO to interact with external world. I.e. - you can accept dto as input from user interface or pass some data to another service or to store data in database. Every layer which is in touch with external world, have to do convertion between DTO <-> your internal Model. You can create special mappers for such convertion. Where to call those mappers? In layers which is in touch with external world.

Comment: Just to point that the domain model/entities (ideally) should be together with the service classes and actually contain most of the business logic. You might want to revisit the dependency as ideally it is `persistance -> domain model <- Web`, so everything depends on the core of the logic.

Comment: Which layer owns DTOs definition? What `createRoom` returns? Which layer owns it?

Comment: @rascio Usually i place my DTOs inside the web layer but in this case the problem is that i 've some DTO that should be in both layers, and others that should be only in one layer but used from another. For example CreateRoomDTO stays inside the Service but is used also in the web layer inside the controller to parse the input

Comment: @tym32167 so in this case i should have a mapper inside the web layer that takes as input a Web Layer DTO and map it into a Service Layer DTO (or is better to say Command)

Comment: yup. Idea is that your domain logic lies in services and working on your internal models. Internal models does not know about DTO. Something like `user -> dto-> web module -> Models -> services -> storage module -> dto -> database`, so your dto will service only 1 purpose - to transfer data. And places where no need to transfer data - they dont need to know anything about dto.

Comment: @SimoneGiannino happy to see you used the term Command, as to me seems the term DTO is used to refer to types of different nature. Imagine you have your service layer contract described in terms of `Command/Query`s and the web layer contract defined in terms of `WebDTO`s, in your web layer you should have functions doing `WebDTO -> Command/Query`. If you are using a `Command` in your web contract, you don't need to transform it (kind of identity function `f(x) = x`). The issue doesn't seem to be where the logic belong, but should you use Command in the web contract? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is borderline opinion-based, but in my view, DTO classes should be used between Service and Web layers and obviously to expose data via your external API. The reason is that if you keep them only in the Web layer it would mean that you will then need to push logic from the Service layer to the Web layer so that the domain model is created from a `CreateRoomDTO` object for example. And you definitely should avoid it because this is logic that should remain in the Service layer.

Comment: Thanks for you response, so in this case all the DTO logic should stay inside the Service Layer and the Web Layer depends and use them?

Comment: Yes, at least that is what I usually do.